# how to convert strings ( a variable holding iterative strings ) into a single list

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I wrote a simple code to fetch object from a given bucket with prefix. I want to only list down the objects which has *.xlsx as extension.
I am stck in a step showing below..

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('suddhasil-bucket-test-1')
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='20190101/US'):
    #print(obj.key)
    keys = (obj.key)
    print(keys)
```

I am getting the objets as :

```
20190101/US/
20190101/US/temp.xls.xlsx
```

But I need only the objects which has "xlsx" extension. to achieve that I need to covert the strings into a list . How can I do that? In my code obj.key is holding the object/key name as string, how can I pull all objects into a list?
Any help would be a great help
Thanks
Tublai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that you are trying to place all objects whose keys end with '.xlsx' into a list, then the simplest change to your existing code would be:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('suddhasil-bucket-test-1')
l = [] # empty list
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='20190101/US'):
    keys = obj.key
    if keys.endswith('.xlsx'):
        l.append(obj) # add obj to l
```

A more succinct way would be to use a *list comprehension*:

```
l = [obj for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='20190101/US') if obj.key.endswith('.xlsx')]
```

And if I have misunderstood what you are trying to accomplish, I can adjust accordingly.

Comment: this is real helpful Srivastava, this is part of code snip . I am trying to get the objects which has *.xlsx extension and restore them only

Comment: Hi Ronald, many thanks this helps . I am having another issue now .. I used the following code ....and getting error "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the RestoreObject operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema". I could not figure out the issue . ANy help would be a great help .... COde is given below...

Comment: response = s3client.restore_object(Bucket='suddhasil-bucket-test-1', Key='20190101/US/temp.xls.xlsx',
                                       RestoreRequest={'Days':1, 'GlacierJobParameters': {'Tier': 'Expedited'},
                                                       'Tier': 'Expedited',
                                                       'OutputLocation': {
                                                           'S3': {'BucketName': 'suddhasil-bucket-test-1',
                                                                  'Prefix': 'Backup_Restore'}}})

Comment: @tublai This question and its answer was about testing the end of a string for a special character sequence. Since this is a completely different problem, you need to open up another question with appropriate tags. Make sure the question is well formatted and you provide enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Use `endswith():`

```
l = []
if keys.endswith('.xlsx'):
    print(keys)
    l.append(keys)
```